# Running iterations selectively with Newman

Tags: postman, newman

I want to run selective iterations from my test file. Say, iterations 10-14. Is there a switch in Newman that I can use to give these inputs. The closest I came is to select the number of iterations to run for which the command is *-n* (Reference [here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/wp-content/qa/uploads/2019/10/output-with-switches-and-their-meanings.jpg)). But this runs all iterations from 1 to n. I want to be able to change the starting and end values.

Comment: You can only run all the iterations and not specific ones.

Comment: oh. Was really hoping for a solution to this. Anyway, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

As @Danny mentioned There is no inbuilt way to specify a specific iteration row to be executed using Newman but can be done using Powershell or by using Newman as a library.

The approaches are as below

**Powershell:**

here we read the actual csv file in the current directory using import csv
Then considers only row 1..2 , if you just want 1 row you can change $a[1..2] to
$[1]

```
$a= Import-Csv .\a.csv
$a[1..2] | Select-Object * | export-csv -Path .\temp.csv -NoTypeInformation
newman run .\test.postman_collection.json -d .\temp.csv
```

**As library:**

here we read and split the csv as we want using csv parser and then write it back to a temp file as csv using csv-stringify library.

**First, install:**

```
npm install csv
npm install fs
npm i fs-extra
npm install newman
```

Then use the below code

```
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project
const stringify = require('csv-stringify')
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync')
const fs = require("fs")
// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
let data = fs.readFileSync('./a.csv',
    { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' });
data = parse(data, {
    columns: true,
    skip_empty_lines: true
})
console.log(data)
//index doesn't consider header so 0 is first data row
stringify(data.slice(0, 2), {
    header: true
}, function (err, output) {

    fs.writeFileSync("temp.csv", output);

    newman.run({
        collection: require('./test.postman_collection.json'),
        reporters: 'cli',
        iterationData: "./temp.csv"
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        console.log('collection run complete!');
    });
})
```